# Does this patent hold true for all carousel view images or card view images in an application?

Tags: apple

In reference to the patent: [USD613300](https://www.google.com/patents/USD613300)

Comment: Are you asking if this design patent keeps others from using a carousel view of images? If so could you edit your question to be more specific and clear?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [design patent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_patent). I'm not an expert, but it basically covers the ornamental design and not the functionality. As long as your display doesn't "look" like this, you should be okay. That said, you really should consult with an actual patent attorney with regards to freedom to operate questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty broad. It does seem limited to left-to-right and there are probably other ways to depict the perspective.